# Buddypress: remove forum tab in user profile page?

Tags: buddypress

I need to remove the forum-tab in user profile pages. I have tried alot of things but no result. I do not want to do it by css.

Tried this: http://www.themightymo.com/2012/01/26/how-to-add-remove-and-change-the-order-of-buddypress-component-menu/ but no luck. Any advice?

Thank you in advance, 
Emily

Comment: Could you add the actual code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function my_setup_nav() {
    global $bp;

    // this cause errors if your not logged-in.
    // $bp->bp_nav['conversations'] = false;

    // use this instead:
    unset($bp->bp_nav['conversations']);
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'my_setup_nav', 1000 );
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for response. Code has no effect unfortunately. Nothing happens at all. 

Using bbpress theme from bbp-theme-compat.
Any idea what could be wrong?